# How can I put a custom xsi:type in a SOAP request created using PHP arrays?

Tags: php, soap, xsitype

How can I create the following part as part of a soap request?

```
<RequestDetails xsi:type="PostcodeRequest">
  <Postcode>SW1A 1AA</Postcode>
</RequestDetails>
```

I am creating the soap request using arrays

```
$aPostcode = array('Postcode'=>'SW1A 1AA')
$aPostcodeRequest = array('PostcodeRequest' => $aPostcode);
$GetLineCharacteristicsRequest = array('RequestDetails' => aPostcodeRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to achieve it using arrays, but I could do it with classes. The code:

```
try {
    $options = [
        'trace'=> 1,
        'location' => 'http://localhost/pruebas/soap-server-nowsdl.php',
        'uri' => 'http://localhost/pruebas'
    ];

    class PostCodeRequest {
        function __construct($pc)
        {
            $this->Postcode = $pc;
        }
    }

    $client = new SOAPClient(null, $options);

    $pc = new PostcodeRequest('SW1A 1AA');
    $postCodeRequest = new SoapVar($pc, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'PostCodeRequest', 'http://soapinterop.org/xsd');
    $response = $client->hola(new SoapParam($postCodeRequest, 'RequestDetails'));

    header('Content-type:text/xml');
    echo $client->__getLastRequest();
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Will give this as request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/pruebas" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://soapinterop.org/xsd" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:hola>
            <RequestDetails xsi:type="ns2:PostCodeRequest">
                <Postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SW1A 1AA</Postcode>
            </RequestDetails>
        </ns1:hola>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Of course, this is assuming you have a "hola" function in your SOAP server. Replace it with whatever you're calling.

This solution is based in the example of the [SoapVar constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php).

Comment: `$response = $client->hola(new SoapParam($postCodeRequest, 'RequestDetails'));`
In that, is `'RequestDetails'` necessary? It does not seems to be used in the XML.

Comment: @JulianJeyarajah it is required, and is used to name the node. If you changed it to, let's say, `'rd'` then the element name would be `<rd xsi:type="ns2:PostCodeRequest">...</rd>`.

Comment: Thank you @Eduardo Galván, for pointed me in the right direction. It worked.